# GPG library for Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, gnupg

Is there any GPG library for Flex 3?

It seems hard to find information about this from Google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a GPG library, but there are some cryptography libraries like [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/). Do you need to interoperate with GPG/PGP or are you implementing your own cryptography system?  The as3crypto library should provide the building blocks you need but you'll have to do some work. Other users on stackoverflow have [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304461/encrypt-decrypt-image-in-actionscript-3) the library too.