# does saving images as swf in flash prevent image theft?

Tags: web, flash, jpeg, image-size

Also when saving images as jpegs, how to avoid images from looking pixelated? 
I really want to prevent image theft. 
any tips?...

Answer (score 0):

If the security of image is so important you need to encrypt it because swf file is easy and simple to decompile and grabbing images from it is really easy.

So if you want to put them in your project safely you have to encrypt them with an algorithm and whenever you want to show it in your project decrypt it with reverse algorithm.

There is a discussion about encrypt and decrypt in AS3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304461/encrypt-decrypt-image-in-actionscript-3)

For pixelated image problem you can when you embed you can check the smooth check box in image properties and when you load it by code you can use smooth property of Bitmap object

```
_imageLoader = new Loader();
            ...
var bitmap:Bitmap = addChild(new Bitmap()) as Bitmap;
bitmap.bitmapData = (_imageLoader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData;
bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = scaleFactor;
bitmap.smoothing = true;
```